# Prob. 20 (a) & (b), Exercises 8.9, in Apostol's CALCULUS vol. 2: If $f^\prime(x;y)=0$ for every $x$ and for every $y$, . . .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Here is Prob. 20, Exercises 8.9, in the book *Calculus* Vol II by Tom M. Apostol, 2nd edition:

> (a)  Assume that $f^\prime ( \mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y} ) = 0$ for every $\mathbf{x}$ in some $n$-ball $B(\mathbf{a})$ and for every vector $\mathbf{y}$. Use the mean-value theorem to prove that $f$ is constant on $B(\mathbf{a})$.
>
> (b) Suppose that $f^\prime ( \mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y} ) = 0$ for a *fixed* vector $\mathbf{y}$ and for every $\mathbf{x}$ in $B(\mathbf{a})$. What can you conclude about $f$ in this case?

And, here is Theorem 8.4 (The Mean-Value Theorem For Derivatives Of Scalar Fields):

> Assume the derivative $f^\prime ( \mathbf{a} + t \mathbf{y}; \mathbf{y} )$ exists for each $t$ in the interval $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Then for some real $\theta$ in the open interval $0 < \theta < 1$ we have
> $$ f ( \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{y} ) - f(  \mathbf{a} ) = f^\prime (  \mathbf{z};  \mathbf{y} ), \ \mbox{ where } \  \mathbf{z} =  \mathbf{a} + \theta  \mathbf{y}. $$

My Attempt:

Part (a)

> Let $\mathbf{x}$ be any point in the $n$-ball $B( \mathbf{a}  )$. Let us put $$\mathbf{y} \colon=  \mathbf{x} -  \mathbf{a}$$
> so that
> $$\mathbf{x} =  \mathbf{a} +  \mathbf{y}. $$
> Then, for any real number $\theta$ in the interval $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$, we find that the point $ \mathbf{a} + \theta \mathbf{y}  $ also lies in the $n$-ball $B( \mathbf{a} )$, and so we must have
> $$ f^\prime ( \mathbf{a} + \theta \mathbf{y} ; \mathbf{y} ) = 0. $$
> Then, for some real number $\theta$ such that $0 < \theta < 1$, we obtain
> $$ f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{a}) = f(\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{y} ) - f( \mathbf{a}) = f^\prime ( \mathbf{a} + \theta \mathbf{y}; \mathbf{y} ) = 0, $$
> and so
> $$ f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{a}) $$
> for every point $\mathbf{x}$ in that $n$-ball. Hence $f$ is constant on the $n$-ball.

Is this proof correct? And if so, then is it clear enough too?

Part (b)

> Since $f^\prime ( \mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y} ) = 0$ for a fixed vector $\mathbf{y}$ and for every $\mathbf{x}$ in $B( \mathbf{a} )$, therefore if $t$ is a real number such that the point $\mathbf{a} + t \mathbf{y}$ is also in $B( \mathbf{a} )$, then we see that, for some real number $\theta \in (0, 1)$, we have
> $$ f( \mathbf{a} + t \mathbf{y} ) - f( \mathbf{a} ) = f^\prime ( \mathbf{a} + \theta t \mathbf{y}; t \mathbf{y} ) = f^\prime ( \mathbf{a} + \theta t \mathbf{y};  \mathbf{y} ) = 0, $$
> and so
> $$ f( \mathbf{a} + t \mathbf{y} ) = f( \mathbf{a} ), $$
> which shows that $f$ does not change along any line through the point $\mathbf{a}$ and parallel to the vector $\mathbf{y}$.

Is each and everything of what I have done (and stated) in Part (b) correct? Or, have I made an error?

P.S.:

Part (b) Continued:

> Now let $\mathbf{x}$ be any other point in $B(\mathbf{a})$. Then using the same argument as above but with $\mathbf{a}$ replaced by $\mathbf{x}$ we can conclude that our scalar field $f$ doesn't change throughout $B(\mathbf{a})$ along any line parallel to the vector $\mathbf{y}$.

Am I right? Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of part (a) is fine, but part (b) is not the general correct result. You should be able, with a slight modification, to show that $f$ does not change along *any* line segment in the ball with direction vector $\mathbf y$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you please have a look at my post now? I've added a P.S.

Comment: Sure. I would write the original argument with $\mathbf x$ in the place of $\mathbf a$ and be done with it  ;)

Comment: so is what I've done correct and just what is required?